# Alterar o valor de um parametro passado para um função

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário dinâmico que eu acrescento vários campos e crio junto uma div que se passa por botão que é atribuído um evento `onClick` para ela passando um função que recebe um parâmetro. Esse parâmetro é um numero sequencial que eu crio através de um `foreach` com um *array* do BD. Porém quando eu clico em adicionar mais um campo, esse parâmetro da função permanece igual, não incrementando. Eu queria poder incrementar o valor do parâmetro, mas não sei como fazer isso via Jquey.

```
<?php 
 $contador = '';
 foreach ($programas as $key => $formu)
 {
   $contador += 1;
 ?>
<div id="campos_<?php echo $contador; ?>" name="campos[]" class="campos col-md-12" >
<br><div class="btn btn-primary"  id="rmv_<?php echo $contador; ?>"   onclick="remover('campos_<?php echo $contador; ?>')"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></div>
</div>
```

repare que eu quero incrementar isto:

```
onclick="remover('campos_<?php echo $contador; ?>')"
```

eu consigo incrementar os demais *id* contadores através de jquery assim:

```
campos.children().find("#rmv_"+(contador)).attr('id','rmv_'+(comentario+1));
```

mas não faço ideia de como fazer para alterar esse valor do parametro.

Alguém que já passou por isso pode me ajudar?

Comment: O ideal no seu caso é você trabalhar de duas maneias separadas, pois php executa no back (servidor) e o jquery no front(cliente). Então você deveria fazer uma proposta para só na hora do update vc enviar todas os campos com seus contadores ou a cada momento que você adicionar o campo você fazer uma chamada ajax ao servidor para te retornar esse campo incrementeado

Comment: é, fazer um ajax é uma boa mesmo, pois o $contador só é incrementado quando passa pelo foreach. Mas será que não tem alguma maneira de segurar o valor do evento via jquery? Pois se houvesse eu poderia substituir por um contador feito via jquery mesmo. Parece ser mais simples, mas claro que ser tiver como.

Comment: Vc quer segurar o contador do php no jquery?
existem 2 maneiras... já q vc mistura php e html/javascript na mesma pagina, vc pode fazer uma variável no javascript que guarda o valor, ou então escrever em um hidden field esse valor e ler ele em javascript

Comment: eu queria na verdade verificar o último valor do contador que no caso poderia ser o valor do ultimo campo, sei lá, verificando isso via jquery e adicionando +1, aí eu poderia pegar esse valor e jogar para o parametro do evento. Meu pior problema é jogar o valor para o parâmetro do evento.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um campo hidden para guardar o valor do seu contador, manipular com javascript e enviar para o backend com ajax ou no post.

```
<?php 
  $contador = '';
  foreach ($programas as $key => $formu)
  {
      $contador += 1;
  }
?>

<input id="contador" name="contador" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $contador; ?>" />

<div id="campos_<?php echo $contador; ?>" name="campos[]" class="campos col-md-12" >
    <br><div class="btn btn-primary"  id="rmv_<?php echo $contador; ?>"   onclick="remover('campos_<?php echo $contador; ?>')"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function criarCampo() {
     var contador = $('#contador').val();

     //incrementa o contador
     +contador++;

     //TODO: Cria o campo com o contador incrementado "campos_"+contador

     //Atualiza o contador no campo hidden

     $('#contador').val(contador);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa simplesmente obter o id (contador) de cada elemento na função `remover()`, pode fazer assim:

```
<br><div class="btn btn-primary"  id="rmv_<?php echo $contador; ?>"   onclick="remover(this)" data-contador="<?php echo $contador; ?>"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></div>
```

E na função `remover()`:

```
function remover() {
   var contador = $(this).data('contador');

   //faça o que tiver que fazer com o contador
}
```